# Why does the Reimer-Tiemann reaction give an ortho product?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds

On treating phenol with chloroform in the presence of sodium hydroxide, a $\ce{-CHO}$ group is introduced at the *ortho* position of the hydroxy group. Why is this so? Why is 4-hydroxybenzaldehyde not obtained?

Comment: I know this might seem unrelated, but do you know about the selectivity in the Kolbe-Schmitt reaction? Treatment of phenol with NaOH and carbon dioxide also gives the ortho product, salicylic acid, exclusively.

Comment: The Reimer-Tiemann reaction generally proceeds in poor yield.  In the case of phenol, both the *ortho* and *para* products are formed in the expected statistical ratio of 2:1 respectively (20% : 10% isolated yield). See [this earlier question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8379/reimer-tiemann-reaction-products) and the link provided in my answer.