# mechanism in bi cyclic compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

In both cases ring expansion is happening. What is Carbon tri chloride purpose?

Comment: I would suggest running a Google search on "carbene addition to alkene". $\ce{CHCl3}$ in alkali medium forms dichlorocarbene $\ce{:CCl2}$.

Comment: Your question b has already been answered  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41500/reaction-of-furan-with-chloroform-in-base

Answer (score 1):

" What is Carbon tri chloride purpose?" is not answered in the link provided but the answer starts with a carbene attack on furan .

Trichloromethane in presence of a base undergoes 1,1-elimination (or an alpha elimination) because both groups are removed from the same carbon.The electron-withdrawing effect of the halogens makes the hydrogen acidic enough to be removed by a strong base such as hydroxide or alkoxide ion.

A halide ion then acts as a leaving group from the conjugate base, producing the
 carbene.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNm40.jpg)

[image]

Carbenes find a pair of electrons  to complete their valence shell of electrons.carbenes attack a lone pair, a C=C double bond (electron-rich or -poor), or even a C–H bond.In its reactions ,

- It is an electrophilic reagent and is known to give ring expansion of aromatic rings.
- Electrophillic attack takes place on pyrrole where the intermediate is most stable.

This leeds to normal Reimer–Tiemann reaction product pyrrole 2-aldehyde.

Carbene attack of a C=C double bond leads to an ring expansion leading to 3-chloropyridine.

[image]

The reaction of bicyclic compounf acts on similar lines of dichloro carbene attack.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaFUn.png)

[image]

**References**

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNm40.jpg) ORGANIC CHEMISTRY ,JOSEPH M. HORNBACK ,UNIVERSITY OF DENVER

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaFUn.png) MARCH’S ADVANCED ORGANIC CHEMISTRY REACTIONS, MECHANISMS,AND STRUCTURE ,SIXTH EDITION

Comment: The second diagram is quite loose with the hydrogen on the nitrogen atom.

Comment: I missed this the first time, but the arrow pushing is backwards in the first step of the pyrrole example.

Comment: @Zhe yes it is pyrrole that donates to dichloro carbene and not other way around.I will corect shortly.