# ortho/para-Selectivity in the Reimer-Tiemann Reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, phenols

I can't figure out why the dichlorocarbene molecule produced in the Reimer-Tiemann reaction gets attached to the *ortho* position of phenol.
The ortho position is sterically slightly more hindered due to the oxygen, so why dosen't the carbene attach to the para position?

[image: Mechanism of carbene generation in Reimer-Tiemann reaction]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Reimer-Tiemann reaction why does phenol attack the carbene from ortho position?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/98188/in-reimer-tiemann-reaction-why-does-phenol-attack-the-carbene-from-ortho-positio)

Comment: No, because this answer was a bit more simple and was straightforward

Comment: @EVO Answers can be simple and straightforward. If they answers your question, then yours is a duplicate of that.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate; the linked duplicate asks about C2 attack vs O attack, not C2 vs C4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Reimer–Tiemann reaction will give a mixture of products unless the formation of one product is highly disfavoured. The Kürti-Csakó notes in its introductory paragraph on the Reimer–Tiemann:<sup>[1]</sup>

> 6. the regioselectivity is not high, but *ortho*-formyl products tend to predominate;

The statement already hints at a product mixture being obtained. To further show that both *ortho* and *para* attacks are possible, the 1960 review published by Wynberg contains the following scheme as its very first scheme in the introduction:<sup>[2]</sup>

[image: General scheme of a Reimer–Tiemann reaction]

So while both products are obtained, a back of the envelope calculation already shows that the distribution is not a perfect $2:1$ ratio. This can apparently be explaned by the effect of positive counterions, as Hine and van der Veen report:<sup>[3]</sup>

> The ratio of *ortho* to *para* product was found to be 2.21 [under high base concentrations], showing that the tendency towards *o*-substitution is indeed increased under conditions where ion-pair formation is encouraged. One factor that would certainly be expected to be present and that would tend to favor *o*-substitution is an electrostatic effect. When a dichloromethylene molecule attacks the *o*-position of a sodium phenoxide ion-pair to yield the probable initial product, there is less separation of unlike charges than when the analogous *para* product is formed.

So while the steric hindrance of a single oxygen atom is not much more than that of a hydrogen atom and thus does not play a huge role, the presence of positive counterions – although increasing steric congestion – may serve to enhance the formation of the *ortho*-product through favourable electronic effects.

---

**References:**

[1]: L. Kürti and B. Czakó: *Strategic Applications of Named Reactions in Organic Synthesis. Background and Detailed Mechanisms*, Elsevier Academic Press, Burlington, MA, USA, **2005**, page 378.

[2]: H. Wynberg, *Chem. Rev.* **1960**, *60*, 169–184. DOI: [10.1021/cr60204a003](https://doi.org/10.1021/cr60204a003).

[3]: J. Hine, J. M. van der Veen, *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1959**, *81*, 6446–6449. DOI: [10.1021/ja01533a028](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01533a028).

Answer (score 1):

In Reimer-Tiemann Reaction, a mixture of ortho and para isomers is obtained in which the ortho isomer predominates (it is not the sole product).
If one of the ortho positions is occupied, the para-isomer is the major product.
The two isomers can be separated by fractional distillation, in which the unreacted phenol and the ortho-isomer distil over leaving behind the para-isomer.
Ortho product is major mainly due to 2 reasons-

1. Probability factor ( there are 2 ortho positions available Vs only 1 para position )
2. H- bonding in the final salisaldehyde.(There is a formation of 6 membered chelated ring which increases the stability of this product.)

Comment: Is the Reimer-Tiemann reaction thermodynamically controlled, such that the product stability determines the outcome? To me, it seems more likely that it's kinetically controlled, where transition state stability is the key.

Comment: Although it is run at refluxing chloroform conditions, I want to agree with orthocresol on this one and think that thermodynamic control is slightly unlikely.